# Can't see interface members while building tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript

Turns out it was user error.  I didn't import the HousingLocation from the correct spot.  As cuzy mentioned I was trying to import the wrong thing from the
'../housing-location/housing-location.component' component.

The correct line is :

import { HousingLocation } from '../housing-location/housing-location.component';

Thanks cuzy!

=======

(leaving this here in case anyone else gets fat-fingered dumb like I did.)

I'm trying to build the app found in this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app

When I get to step 11, we're declaring a variable using an interface.  However, I can't see the members of the interface in my calling component.

**housing-location.component.ts contents:** (contains interface)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Housinglocation } from '../housinglocation';
import {RouterLink, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-housing-location',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    RouterLink, 
    RouterOutlet],
  template: `
<section class="listing">
    <img class="listing-photo" [src]="HousingLocation.photo" alt="Exterior photo of {{HousingLocation.name}}">
    <h2 class="listing-heading">{{ HousingLocation.name }}</h2>
    <p class="listing-location">{{ HousingLocation.city}}, {{HousingLocation.state }}</p>
    <a [routerLink]="['/details', HousingLocation.id]">Learn More</a>
  </section>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./housing-location.component.css']
})
export class HousingLocationComponent {
  @Input() HousingLocation!: HousingLocation
}

export interface HousingLocation {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  photo: string;
  availableUnits: number;
  wifi: boolean;
  laundry: boolean;
}
```

**details.component.ts** (uses the interface from above)

```
import { Component,inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HousingService } from '../housing.service';
import { Housinglocation } from '../housinglocation';
import { HousingLocationComponent } from '../housing-location/housing-location.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    HousingLocationComponent
  ],
  template: `
   <article>
    <img class="listing-photo" [src]="Housinglocation?.photo"
      alt="Exterior photo of {{Housinglocation?.name}}"/>
    <section class="listing-description">
      <h2 class="listing-heading">{{Housinglocation?.name}}</h2>
      <p class="listing-location">{{Housinglocation?.city}}, {{Housinglocation?.state}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="listing-features">
      <h2 class="section-heading">About this housing location</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Units available: {{Housinglocation?.availableUnits}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have wifi: {{Housinglocation?.wifi}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have laundry: {{Housinglocation?.laundry}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </article> 
`,
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent {
    route: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
    housingLocationId = -1;
    housingService = inject(HousingService);
    Housinglocation: Housinglocation | undefined;
    myHousingLocation = "";
  
  
    constructor() {
      this.housingLocationId = Number(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
      this.Housinglocation = this.housingService.getHousingLocationById(this.housingLocationId);
  }
}
```

When I try to compile I get red squigglies under each of the interface properties (i.e., .photo, .name, .availableUnits, etc.).  I can't figure out why the details component can't see the properties of the interface.  Does anyone see where I've gone wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Shouldn't `import { Housinglocation } from '../housinglocation';` be more like `import { Housinglocation } from '../housing-location.component';`?

Comment: That does seem to be it.  I guess I must have mistyped that to begin with.  Thanks!